# ICs on opposite sides of a PCB

Tags: pcb-design, audio, eaglecad, differential

I am relatively new to PCB design and circuits in general. I am routing my first 4 layer board now and I am wondering about placing ICs on top of each other on opposite sides of the PCB. The ICs in question are fully differential op amps, part MCP6D11. They all are running on 3.3v and will have a gain of 1. I am wondering if it is okay to place the parts on top of each other on opposite sides of the PCB with their ground pads connected to each other through vias as show in the pictures below. Will this cause any signal integrity issues in the audio rate analog domain? Will it be a pain to hot air solder them if their ground pads are connected so closely? Any other issues that I am not thinking of? [image][image][image]

Comment: If you solder one, then flip the board over and try to solder the other one, what will be holding the first one on? Industry uses epoxy adhesive, but can't do that with an exposed ground pad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are concerned about signal integrity then you most certainly want to have internal planes. Your best bet would be to have two internal ground planes to provide a low-impedance return path, as well as shielding between the chips. So to answer your question, no - there probably won't be an issue with putting one chip "above" another on the opposite side of the board provided you have internal ground planes.

When it comes to hot air soldering, yes - it will be more difficult to solder parts with a connection to a large mass of copper because said copper will wick away the heat more easily. A good hot air tool will be able to overcome this though.

Comment: I have not added the vias yet but my layers are 1 - signal 2 - power 3 - ground 4 - signal. Would it be better to put a ground plane on layers 2 and 3 for this section of the board? Or will it be fine to ground both op amps to layer 4 and save layer 2 for power like the rest of the board?

Comment: For audio-frequency analog circuits it's probably fine to have power and ground planes for the two internal layers. However, when it comes to higher-speeds (especially digital with fast edges) it's generally preferred to have two internal ground planes and power polygons on the top and bottom layers, due to the way the PCB is constructed. This more tightly couples the power and ground areas to one another which reduces EMI (again, not as much of an issue in your application).